# k3s - select ingress nodes with default traefik

Tags: k3s

I have a k3s cluster with

- 1 master + 2 nodes
- default traefik as ingress

Traefik is running on the master node.

- Is there a way to label nodes / change manifest so that traefik runs on the nodes instead of the master?
- Is there a reason for default traefik to run on the master node?

Answer (score 0):

See discussion for work arounds and reasoning: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1684